# Summarize log data into change history with SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has time-stamped action records for an employee. Each record has a department and a work title. Now I want to extract what changes have occurred when the employee changed departments and/or work title.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Assuming our table holds records for a simple employee, the data could look like this:

```
Time |  Department | WorkTitle
t1        Dep1         Wt1    <---
t2        Dep1         Wt1
t3        Dep2         Wt2    <---
t4        Dep2         Wt2
t5        Dep1         Wt1    <---
t6        Dep3         Wt1    <---
t7        Dep3         Wt1
t8        Dep3         Wt1
```

I want to extract the first instance when the employee appears in a new department and/or has a new work title.

In the above data, the records with arrows should be the ones extracted and it should result in the following results:

```
Time |  Department | WorkTitle
t1        Dep1         Wt1
t3        Dep2         Wt2
t5        Dep1         Wt1
t6        Dep3         Wt1
```

Note that at time t1 and t5 the same department and work title occur, so a simple GROUP BY clause does not work.

I have tried some attempts using OVER/PARTITION, but the complexity of this query seems to be beyond my knowledge.

Can this be done using an SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff said, this problem is really easy when you have [lag()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function. SQL Server 2008 doesn't have it, so I prefer to solve it with [outer apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select t1.*
from t as t1
    outer apply (
        select top 1 t2.*
        from t as t2
        where t2.worktime < t1.worktime
        order by t2.worktime desc
    ) as t2
where
    t2.worktime is null or
    t2.department <> t1.department or
    t2.worktitle <> t1.worktitle
```

Comment: I ended up with this solution after specifying employee:
select t1.UserName, t1.ClosingTimestamp, t1.CurrentDepartmentName, t1.CurrentWorkPeriodEnd
from IssueView as t1
    outer apply (
        select top 1 t2.*
        from IssueView as t2
        where t2.ClosingTimestamp < t1.ClosingTimestamp            and
              t2.EmployeeSsn = 'xxx'
        order by t2.ClosingTimestamp desc
    ) as t2
where
    (t2.ClosingTimestamp is null or
    t2.CurrentDepartmentName <> t1.CurrentDepartmentName or
    t2.CurrentWorktitleName <> t1.CurrentWorktitleName) and
    t1.EmployeeSsn = 'xxx'

Answer (score 3):

The function you really need is `lag()`, but that is not available until SQL Server 2012.  In its absence, I prefer a correlated subquery.

This approach retrieves the previous time, then joins the table back in, and does the comparison for filtering:

```
select tprev.*
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 time
              from t t2
              where t.time < t2.time
              order by time desc
             ) as prevtime
      from t
     ) tprev join
     t
     on tprev.prevtime = t.time
where tprev.department <> t.department or
      tprev.worktitle <> t.worktitle or
      tprev.prevtime is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this non-[triangular join](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/) solution:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(
    -- You should use appropiate data types for every column
    [Time]      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Department  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    WorkTitle   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @MyTable ([Time],Department,WorkTitle)
SELECT 't1', 'Dep1', 'Wt1'
UNION ALL SELECT 't2', 'Dep1', 'Wt1'
UNION ALL SELECT 't3', 'Dep2', 'Wt2'
UNION ALL SELECT 't4', 'Dep2', 'Wt2'
UNION ALL SELECT 't5', 'Dep1', 'Wt1'
UNION ALL SELECT 't6', 'Dep3', 'Wt1'
UNION ALL SELECT 't7', 'Dep3', 'Wt1'
UNION ALL SELECT 't8', 'Dep3', 'Wt1';

DECLARE @ResultsWithRowNum TABLE
(
    RowNum      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Time]      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Department  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    WorkTitle   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @ResultsWithRowNum(RowNum,[Time],Department,WorkTitle)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.[Time]) AS RowNum,x.[Time],x.Department,x.WorkTitle
FROM    @MyTable x;

WITH RecursiveCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  crt.RowNum,
            crt.[Time],
            crt.Department,
            crt.WorkTitle,
            1 AS IsFirstRowNewGroup
    FROM    @ResultsWithRowNum crt
    WHERE   crt.RowNum=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  crt.RowNum,
            crt.[Time],
            crt.Department,
            crt.WorkTitle,
            CASE WHEN prev.Department = crt.Department AND prev.WorkTitle = crt.WorkTitle THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM    @ResultsWithRowNum crt
    INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE prev ON crt.RowNum = prev.RowNum + 1
)
SELECT  *
FROM    RecursiveCTE rec
WHERE   rec.IsFirstRowNewGroup = 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Results:

```
RowNum Time Department WorkTitle IsFirstRowNewGroup
------ ---- ---------- --------- ------------------
1      t1   Dep1       Wt1       1
3      t3   Dep2       Wt2       1
5      t5   Dep1       Wt1       1
6      t6   Dep3       Wt1       1
```